# How to set PIxelFormat to rgb in javafx?

Tags: java, image, javafx

With javafx, when I read images the PixelFormat is rgb and I want to apply filters on them.I use writableImage.pixelWriter to set the pixels color but the PixelFormat is rgba.

I use ImageIO.write() and it work for .png, but when I try to save this modified image in .jpg or .jpeg, the color change. I find that's because rgba don't work with jpg but i don't know how to change this PixelFormat.

Is there a way to change rgba format in rgb ? Do you know another way to save javafx Image as .jpg/.jpeg ?

Edit : How I save file (it works for png)

```
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG Files", "*.jpg"));
File outputFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(modifiedImage.getImage(), null); // getImage() return a javafx.scene.image.Image;
try {
           ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", outputFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

How I modify image (example)

```
Image currentImage = modifiedImage.getImage();
WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int) currentImage.getWidth(), (int) currentImage.getHeight());
PixelReader pixelReader = currentImage.getPixelReader();
PixelWriter pixelWriter = writableImage.getPixelWriter();

for (int i = 0; i < (int) currentImage.getWidth(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < (int) currentImage.getHeight(); j++) {    
           pixelWriter.setColor(i, j, new Color(0,0,0,1)); 
      }
}
modifiedImage.setImage(writableImage);
```

When I get the PixelFormat of the reader it's rgb but for the writer it's rgba. If I save an image without modification it's good, but when I apply a filter on it and I save the image as jpg, the colors change.

On my app the colors are good but if I open the jpg file outside they aren't. With png files there is no problem. I can allow to save only as png but it would be better if i can choose.

Solution :

```
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(modifiedImage.getImage(), null);
BufferedImage bImage2 = new BufferedImage(bImage.getWidth(), bImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
bImage2.getGraphics().drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, null);
try {
     ImageIO.write(bImage2, "jpg", outputFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code how you use ImageIO to write the pixels? Basically the 'a' in rgba 'a' is the alpha channel. If you want rgb then just use the 'r', 'g' and 'b' channels and skip the alpha channel. Not sure if i understood your question correctly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are again one of the many people who are hit by this bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8119048 which is not considered important enough to be fixed. If you read the comments in there you will find a work-arround. Basically the idea is to copy the image after the conversion into a new image without alpha channel.
I'd really like to know how many more people have to waste their time until this bug finally gets enough attention to be fixed.